# I am getting a module not found error in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Here is my code

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

top = tkinter.Tk()

def helloCallBack():
    Tkinter.messagebox.showinfo( "Hello Python", "Hello World")

B = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Hello", command = helloCallBack)

B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\23470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\top.py", line 2, in <module>
    import Tkmessagebox
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkmessagebox'
```

Comment: The code in your post imports `tkMessageBox`, but the error message talks about `Tkmessagebox`. So which is it?

Comment: Also your code says `import Tkinter` but you are using `tkinter.Tk()` and Tkinter.messagebox. Are you using pyton2 or python 3?

Comment: I am using python 3

Comment: in python 3 it is `tkinter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox

top = tkinter.Tk()

def helloCallBack():
    messagebox.showinfo( "Hello Python", "Hello World")

B = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Hello", command = helloCallBack)

B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Also usually people use `import tkinter as tk` so they don't have to write `tkinter.Tk` and `tkinter.Button`. To use that shortcut look at this:

```py
import tkinter as tk # Import tkinter but put it inside `tk`
from tkinter import messagebox

top = tk.Tk() # Use tk.Tk instead

def helloCallBack():
    messagebox.showinfo("Hello Python", "Hello World")

B = tk.Button(top, text="Hello", command=helloCallBack) # Use tk.Button instead

B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```